# Using the property value of a Class to affect another Class object based on time

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Currently I am trying to learn how to use es6 classes for an application I am working on.

The goal is to increase the age of an animal based on the current date.

The Animal Class
`Animal.js`

```js
class Animal {

    constructor(name, age, species, gender, activity, birthday, hunger = 100, stamina = 100, happy = 100) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.species = species;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.hunger = hunger;
        this.stamina = stamina;
        this.happy = happy;
        this.birthday = birthday
    }
    birthday() {
        this.age++
        console.log(`Happy birthday to ${this.name}, ${this.name} is now ${this.age}`)
    }
}
module.exports = Animal
```

The Time Class
`Time.js`

```js
class Time {
    constructor() {
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.days = 1;
        this.season = 1;
        this.year = 0;
        this.clock = `${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`;
        this.monthDate = `${this.season}/${this.days}`
        this.yearDate = `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}`
        this.timeStamp = `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}-${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`

        // Start timer when 
        this.countTime = setInterval(this.increaseTime.bind(this), 1000)
    }

    increaseTime() {
        this.clock = `${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`
        this.monthDate = `${this.season}/${this.days}`
        this.yearDate = `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}`
        this.timeStamp = `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}-${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`

        console.log(this.clock)
        if (this.seconds === 60) {
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.minutes++
            if (this.minutes === 1) {
                this.minutes = 0;
                this.days++
                console.log(this.timeStamp)
                if (this.days === 15) {
                    this.days = 0;
                    this.season++
                    if (this.season > 4) {
                        this.season = 1;
                        this.year++
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            this.seconds++
        }
    }

}

module.exports = Time;
```

Here is where I try to utilize them both:
`Zoo.js`

```js
const Animal = require("./Animal");
const Time = require("./Time");

let time1 = new Time();

let gary = new Animal("Gary", 10, "Gorilla", "Male", "Sleeping", '1/2')
if (time1.monthDate === gary.birthday) {
     gary.birthday()
}
```

So based off of the value of time1.monthDate (which is always changing because I have a setInterval function within the Time class), I will execute a function within the Animal Class to increase Gary's age.

I realize that in this current state, that I need to constantly run this check, so I have also tried this:

```js
while (time1) {
    if (time1.monthDate === gary.birthday) {
        gary.birthday();
    }
}
```

This also does not work although I am constantly running this check.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.birthday = birthday` and having a `birthday()` method at the same time won't work.

Comment: I would recommend to remove the `this.countTime = setInterval(this.increaseTime.bind(this), 1000)` from your `Time` constructor. Instead, instantiate `time1` and `gary`, then create the interval that does `setInterval(function() { time1.increaseTime(); if (time1.monthDate === gary.birthday)  gary.birthday(); }, 1000)`

Comment: Btw, inside `increaseTime` you probably want to update `clock`, `monthDate`, `yearDate` and `timeStamp` *after* you increased the seconds. Or even better, drop them completely, and make getters instead so that the time is formatted only when you access it.

Comment: That did it for me! Now I'm onto the next challenge where I need to make sure he stops aging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> This also does not work although I am constantly running this check.

That's because *no other code can run while that loop runs*. That includes the setInterval callback that increases the time.

Instead, why don't you provide a way to schedule a callback to the timer tick:

```
 class Time {
    constructor() {
      this.seconds = 0;
      this.minutes = 0;
      this.days = 1;
      this.season = 1;
      this.year = 0;
      this.handlers = []; // < collect handlers
      // Start timer when 
    this.countTime = setInterval(this.increaseTime.bind(this), 1000)
    }

    get clock() { // if this is a getter, it is always up to date
      return `${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`;
    }
    get monthDate() {
       return `${this.season}/${this.days}`;
    }
    get yearDate() {
       return `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}`;
    }
    get timeStamp () {  
        return  `${this.season}/${this.days}/${this.year}-${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`;
    }

    increaseTime() {
      this.seconds++
      if (this.seconds === 60) {
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.minutes++;
      }
      if (this.minutes === 1) {
         this.minutes = 0;
         this.days++;
      }               
      if (this.days === 15) {
        this.days = 0;
        this.season++
     }
     if (this.season > 4) {
        this.season = 1;
        this.year++
     }

     this.handlers.forEach(h => h(this)); // < trigger handlers
  }

  onTick(h) { this.handlers.push(h); }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
time1.onTick(() => {
  if (time1.monthDate === gary.birthday) {
    gary.birthday();
  }
});
```